# StringUtils concurrency exception

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-stringutils

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(StringUtils.java:3428)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(StringUtils.java:3513)
```

For running `StringUtils.join`

The `StringUtils` documentation mentions: `#ThreadSafe#`

What is wrong? The code is located in a java class that implements Callable.

My full code:

```
public class MyApiCallable implements Callable<ResponseType> {

    final List<String> itemsId;

    MyApiCallable(List<String> itemsId) {
        this.itemsId = itemsId;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseType call() throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget baseTarget = client.target("http://whatever.com").path("path").queryParam("ItemID", StringUtils.join(itemsId,",",));
        ResponseType rs = target.request().get(ResponseType.class);
        return rs;
    }
}
```

and here is the method that calls the callable:

```
private Future<ResponseType> addGetMultipleItems(ExecutorService executor, List<String> itemIds) {
        Callable<ResponseType> shoppingCallable = new MyApiCallable(itemIds);
        Future<ResponseType> shoppingResult = executor.submit(shoppingCallable);
        return shoppingResult;
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to add/remove from a collection through an interator. You aren't allowed to do that. Keep in mind that enhanced for loops use an iterator under the hood

Comment: Threadsafe means that the function cannot break anything by itself, but it's still possible for it to manifest breakage happening elsewhere. You are modifying the passed-in list in another thread.

Comment: why not actually include the code in question in the question?

Comment: @VinceEmigh it's not me- it's a method that belongs to StringUtils

Comment: This may not be safe if the list is actually being concurrently modified, even though it's annotated thread-safe...

Comment: @Dejel the problem doesn't seem to be a method of StringUtils, but what you pass to it - but please, show us the code in question so we can see.

Comment: How about locating that code on your post !!

Comment: @eis pls see the code

Comment: Some other thread modifies the `itemsId`list while `StringUtils.join()` is iterating on it. `StringUtils.join()` is thread-safe. But the list you pass to the method is not.

Comment: do u mean that I need to clone the itemIds for this.itemsId = itemsId;?

Comment: Cloning the list would do the same thing as StringUtils.join() does: it would iterate on the list to copy all its elements to a new list. You need to use a thread-safe list, or to synchronize all the accesses to the list properly, or to avoid sharing this list between threads, or avoid to modify it once it has been constructed and passed to threads. The design problem is in code you don't show.

Comment: Try cloning the collection in the constructor:
Instead of `this.itemsId = itemsId;` use `this.itemsId = new ArrayList<>(itemsId);`. You'll see the problem disappears because some thread modifies your **itemsId** collection.

Comment: @JBNizet is there a way inside MyApiCallable to make it not changed?

Comment: @RobertDanci what do you think of JBNizert answer?

Comment: MyApiCallable only iterates through the list. It doesn't modify it. Some other code, executed by another thread, modifies it.

Comment: @JBNizet correct - however will new ArrayList<String>(itemIds) solve it?

Comment: Creating a new list will solve the problem. Also please consider Guava's [`ImmutableList`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained), which gives thread safety through immutability.

Comment: @RobertDanci can you pls write as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Creating a new list can solve the problem **if** the copy of the list is done in the same thread than the one modifying the list and causing the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Copying the list in the constructor won't necessariily fix the problem, since the list could be modified by another thread when it is being copied in the constructor.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks - it's a callable class - a new thread that is opened just for it. I guess that it would help no? as that thread cannot modify the list

Comment: @Dejel JB Nizet is correct, usually _cloning_ happens by looping over the elements. Luckily cloning an ArrayList from an ArrayList copies the backing array so it won't throw a ConcurrentModificationException. But Magnamag is right, some thread could modify the list while you are constructing MyApiCallable so you can get unpredictable results. The solution would be to clone the list before **addGetMultipleItems** gets called or synchronize it.